# Question about multiplying a vector by a scalar when the data type is 8-bit using aarch64 assembly

Tags: simd, intrinsics, neon, arm64

I was solving a problem that multiply an 8-bit array A by an 8-bit array B.

Here, I treat A as a vector, and each element in B as a scalar.

For example, if A is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, and B is {1,2},

Then I will get {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} x {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} + {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2} x {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, here '+' means concat.

But sth confused me.

I know that it can be done by this when the data type is 16-bit or 32-bit from https://www.element14.com/community/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/41836-102-1-229511/ARM.Reference_Manual.pdf

I see that

```
SMULL Vd.<Ta>, Vn.<Tb>, Vm.<Ts>[index]
Signed integer multiply long (vector, by element). Where <Ta>/<Tb>/<Ts> is 4S/4H/H or 2D/2S/S. If <Ts>
is H, then Vm must be in the range V0-V15
```

But there is only H, D, or S, B is not supported.

If I use **DUP** instead, then I will use many more neon regisiters to save the data, which means that, if the data is Vn.16B, then I must use 16 **DUP** instructions to load the 16 Vm.8B data, and then multiply each one by A. However, if I can use the **SMULL** , I just use one neon regisiter to save the data because I can use the index to represent the scalar.

I don't know if there is any other efficient way to achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: The reference manual link is broken.